# GraphQL not calling custom scalar methods

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, graphql-js

As many others, I'm trying to create my own `Date` scalar using GraphQL with JavaScript. I've read many examples and followed [this guide from apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars.html) in particular.

### What I've done

- Added `scalar Date` to my schema
- Created an instance of `GraphQLScalarType`, with my implementations of serialize, parseValue and parseLiteral. I called that instance `dateScalar`
- Added a new property to the resolvers map that is called `Date` and its value is `dateScalar`

This should make my `Date` ready to be used according to what I've read. However, the value I get every time I do a query is exactly the same value that I have stored in the database. If that was a string, I see a string, if that was a number, I see a number. It's not parsed or serialized at any moment.

This is how my files look like.

**schema.js**

```js
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

const schema = buildSchema(`
  scalar Date

  # more schema
`);

module.exports = schema;
```

**root.js**

```js
const { dateScalar } = require('./customScalars');

const root = {
  // queries

  // mutations

  // scalars
  Date: dateScalar
};

module.exports = root;
```

**customScalars.js**

```js
const { GraphQLScalarType } = require('graphql');

const dateScalar = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Date',
  description: 'This is a scalar version of the js Date',
  serialize(value) {
    console.log('call serialize');
    return value.getTime();
  },
  parseValue(value) {
    console.log('call parseValue');
    return new Date(value).getFullYear();
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    console.log('call parseLiteral');
    return;
  }
});

module.exports = {
  dateScalar
};
```

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');

const schema = require('./graphql/schema.js');
const graphqlRoot = require('./graphql/root.js');

var app = express();
app.use('/endpoint', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  graphiql: true,
  rootValue: graphqlRoot,
}));

app.listen(3333, () => console.log('Now browse to localhost:3333/endpoint'));
```

### My debug so far

- I've used logs on the methods`serialize`, etc, and none of them is called.
- I've removed `Date` property from the root, and the behaviour is exactly the same
- I've checked that the instance of `dateScalar` does what I expect. I've done so by calling `console.log(dateScalar.serialize(new Date().getTime()))` just after importing it in different files. When doing that I get the log telling me that serialize was called, and the result is what I was expecting.

It seems like at the root it never linked the scalar from my schema with my custom scalar instance. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

My guess is that GraphQL is serializing and parsing using `.toString()`, as it doesn't find my implementations for serializing/parsing.

**Any ideas about how to make GraphQL use my custom scalar?**

Comment: You wrote you "added a new property to the root that is called Date". Not sure what is the "root" here. Is it a resolvers map? or is it something else?
Can you copy here the relevant part of the root and how you set your graphQLOptions.schema?

Comment: @talzaj Oh that's a good point. It was actually the resolvers map, but I didn't realize that root is not the common lingo for it. I'll edit the question adding some code so it can be clearly understood. Thanks!

Comment: I actually implemented it successfully on my server yesterday. So if you're still having problems, I can compare your code to what works for me.

Comment: that sounds great. I need my personal laptop to get the code that I wrote to be able to update this post. Hopefully this evening I'll find the time to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @talzaj I've just updated the post. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

use `graphql-tools` to make an executable schema and use `apollo-server-express` instead of `express-graphql`

---

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with `express-graphql`. So my solution requires replaching it with `apollo-server-express`. Luckily it doesn't require many changes.

This is what works for me with some modifications to match your code.

Install packages first:
`npm install apollo-server-express graphql-tools`

And here's the code:

```
const {makeExecutableSchema} = require('graphql-tools')
const {graphqlExpress} = require('apollo-server-express');

const graphqlRoot = require('./graphql/root.js');

//...

const schemaDef = `
  scalar Date

  # more schema
`;

//build the schema
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: [schemaDef],
  resolvers: graphqlRoot
});

// your new endpoint:
app.use('/endpoint', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema }));
```

Read more about [Adding a GraphQL endpoint](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/setup.html)

Also, with Apollo it is easy to have multiple schema files and resolvers files without having to worry about combining them manually. Here's an explanation from the documentation: [Modularizing the schema](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html#modularizing)

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I can and accept your answer once I have it working. Thanks for answering! :)

Comment: There seems to be a non-trivial amount of work to transition to apollo libraries. I cannot find the way to get this working. Now I'm getting the error "Expected undefined to be a GraphQL schema" and all the stack trace points to node_libraries files.

Comment: can you post your code including where you set your endpoint, call `graphqlExpress` with the params and the code where you assign your schema?